# can same private IP will communicate?

Tags: networking

Suppose Company A's Lan's network address is 192.168.10.0/24 and B's LAN network's address is 192.168.10./24. when company A brought company B..then as usual they also need to make communication between two network.....but the A's and and B's network IP address are same....so how can they reach to each other...then that time should we have to change B's Lan Ip address? or do we have any other options? –

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

Comment: should we have to change Someone's IP address???Either A's or B's

Comment: If they need to communicate directly, you need to change one of the ranges.

Answer (score 1):

They can communicate just fine if at least one of them is NATed to another range/IP (private or public) on the way to the other.

But it's safer to change one of the ranges, e.g. to avoid problems in network documentation